# Use copied text in Testcafe Naviagation to change URL

Tags: url, testing, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I select some text with

```
t.selectText(Selector('#neededURL'), 0, 60) [can copy it if needed]
```

and want to use this text in `navigateTo` function, how can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

const url = Selector('#neededURL').value
await t.navigateTo(url).